# Get the site owners information from a site collection

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, powershell

Can someone share the query to get Site owner and site collection manager information from all sites and sub-sites in a SharePoint 2013 site collection?

Comment: what you mean by site collection manager?

Comment: I mean site collection administrator.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming by "site collection manager" you mean "site collection administrator" then this script should do the trick to help you identify content owners:
http://techtrainingnotes.blogspot.com/2014/11/sharepoint-use-powershell-to-get-all.html?m=1
Per the above script, this will get you all owners:

```
Get-SPSite -Limit All | 
Get-SPWeb -Limit All | 
where { $_.HasUniquePerm -and $_.AssociatedOwnerGroup -ne $null } | 
foreach { $TTNweburl = $_.Url; $_ } | 
Select -ExpandProperty AssociatedOwnerGroup | 
Select -ExpandProperty Users | 
Select {$TTNweburl}, UserLogin, DisplayName
```

Comment: Please avoid just posting a link as an answer. You should **cite the relevant parts of the linked content** in case the link breaks or the linked site goes down.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I'll improve my answers, but as a fellow blogger, I'd much rather send the asker to the author than copying and pasting parts of the author's post here. Thoughts?

Comment: thanks for the response but I am looking for all sites/sub-sites owner information not all users having full control permission. can you provide if you have any script or suggestion.

Comment: The first script from the link gives you all owners..I've added it to my answer above.